# Using file_put_contents on android with php server writes a file, but a Windows user using a USB cable to the device cant see it

Tags: php, android, chmod

I'm using a web server with PHP on my android device, and it works great. I have a form that ultimately ends up in a file after I write it with file_put_contents.

The thing is that if I use a file manager on the device, I can see the file, but not if I try to access it in Windows explorer using a USB cable to the device. And if I *copy* the file in said file manager to the same folder, but to another name, I can see the file using a USB cable in Windows explorer.

I would like a smooth way of accessing this file from a Windows PC without using SSH servers (which works. If i ssh to the device I can see it and copy it) or using a file manager on my Android device to copy it to my PC (which also works since I can just set some folder shared in Windows).

All files should have atleast read-rights on them, and they're being written in a folder that's on the sdcard on the device (hence its a fat-system = not chmoddable?). The device isn't rooted, and I'd like if it stayed that way (but it might actually be this I need to do to fix it?)

If I list the files it says that all file owners are root, even if its a file that's been created in Windows and copied to my document root with Windows explorer (those files are always visible by Windows explorer, it's just the files created by file_put_contents that doesn't show up). If I try the exact same code on an Windows apache server the files shows up right as they're supposed to be.

Hope I made myself clear, and I hope someone can point me in the right direction! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem had nothing to do with my code, but rather the case of the "you have to restart your device to show your files in explorer"-syndrom. I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but that's a heads up anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can create a file with windows, check the owner of the windows file and then create a file with "file_put_contents" and check their owner.

Then you can change the owner of the file to the windows user, if the web user is the root.

Or try to use 0777 as chmod ;) Give it a try ...

Comment: All files, whether I created them in Windows or with file_put_contents, is -rw-rw-r-- root. The windows files shows and the file_put_contents doesn't. Chmod doesn't change anything actually. If I do php chmod it says I dont have the permission, and if I use shell_exec chmod nothing happends